# Skip execute an Validation Rule in AbstractValidator

Tags: java, validation

In Java, I create a class extends `AbstractValidator<SiteContact>` like this:

```
public class MyValidator extends AbstractValidator<MyStudent> {

  public CreateSiteContactValidator() {
    ruleFor( myStudent -> myStudent.getStudentId() )
        .must( getStudentId-> CommonValidatorUtils.isValidUUID(getStudentId) )
        .withMessage(" The getStudentIdvalue is invalid ");

    ruleFor( myStudent -> myStudent.getGradeId() )
        .must( getGradeId -> !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(getGradeId) )
        .withMessage(" The getGradeId is invalid ");

    ruleFor( myStudent -> myStudent.getEmail() )
        .must(CommonValidatorUtils::isEmailValidTemplate)
        .withMessage(" The email is invalid value ");

    ruleFor(myStudent::getClassId)
        .must(CommonValidatorUtils::isValidUUID)
        .withMessage(" The getClassId value is invalid. ");

  }

}
```

In some case, I don't need to validate for classId. Is there any way to skip this rule when execute?

Comment: What framework is this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is FluentValidation, you can use [conditions](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).